# Suggest php based weekly and daily calendar

Tags: php

I have monthly view calendar, i am looking for any weekly and daily view calendar(php based).

Comment: What are you using currently for your monthly view one? Can you use it's code to make it output weekly/daily information?

Answer (score 2):

[Google suggests](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+calendar+with+weekly+monthly+and+daily+view):

[The MyBB Calendar](http://wiki.mybb.com/index.php/Calendar)
[ApPHP Calendar](http://www.apphp.com/php-calendar/index.php?page=getting_started)
[Comdev Events Calendar](http://www.comdevweb.com/calendar.php)
[SuperCali PHP Event Calendar](http://supercali.inforest.com/demo.php)
[LuxCal Web Based Event Calendar](http://www.luxsoft.eu/index.php?pge=luxcal)
[ExtCalendar 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/extcal/)

I could go on, but I think you could probably do a better job of evaluating these yourself